# Why would clicks be zero for Google Ad campaigns in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics under Acquisition -> Google Ads, why would the 'clicks' metric return 0 for each campaign when the sessions are being generated for each campaign? Has something been set up incorrectly?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to link Google Ads to Google Analytics from Property settings.

Comment: Also auto-taggings needs to be enabled in Google Ads, and clicks, cost and cpc will default to 0 if any segments are applied.

Comment: @EikePierstorff ah I have a segment applied (filtering traffic who have seen a certain page), is there no way around the clicks, cost and cpc defaulting to 0 for segments?